# After upgrading to iTextSharp v5.5.8+ invalid pdf

Tags: itext

I'm working on a C# application that creates reports by opening a template and adding text and tables.
This works fine in iTextSharp v5.5.6

Because I need to make some adjustments to the code I want to upgrade to the latest version: v5.5.13

The pdf is still created. I have no problem viewing it in pdfJS but after downloading and opening it in Adobe Acrobat Reader I get an error about something not right in the document. The document is still shown correctly.

When I validate the PDF in https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx I get this result:

```
Compliance  pdf1.7
Result  Document does not conform to PDF/A.
Details Validating file "foo.pdf" for conformance level pdf1.7
The name Xf1 of a xobject resource is unknown.
The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The document doesn't conform to the PDF reference (missing required entries, wrong value types, etc.).
The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
The document does not conform to the PDF 1.7 standard.
```

The pdf created with v5.5.6 returns:

```
Compliance  pdf1.7
Result  Document validated successfully.
Details Validating file "foo.pdf" for conformance level pdf1.7
The document does conform to the PDF 1.7 standard.
```

I tried all versions between v5.5.6 and v5.5.13 and since v5.5.8 I'm getting this error.

Most likely I need to adjust my code but I am not sure how. I did check the changelogs but couldn't find anything related to this error.

Here's some code:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var document = new Document();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
writer.PageEvent = new MyPageEventHandler();
document.Open();

writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
writer.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;
writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
writer.SetFullCompression();

document.SetMargins(33, 33, 35, 55);
document.AddTitle(title);
document.AddAuthor("foo");
document.AddSubject(subject);
document.AddAuthor("bar");
document.AddCreationDate();
document.AddProducer();
document.AddLanguage("NL");
document.AddCreator("fooMore");

// Add some text and table data
---
writer.CloseStream = false;
document.Close();
ms.Position = 0;
return ms;
```

Comment: Please share a sample PDF with the issue for analysis. Following that there likely will follow requests for some specific code parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the *PdfAWriter* class to create PdfA documents using iText 5.
This class already covers a few requirements that are enforced by the PDF/A standard. It will also generate an exception if a certain requirement is not met.

```
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10);
        Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4,
                MARGIN_OF_ONE_CM, MARGIN_OF_ONE_CM, MARGIN_OF_ONE_CM, MARGIN_OF_ONE_CM);
        PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(DEST), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
        document.addAuthor("Author");
        document.addSubject("Subject");
        document.addLanguage("nl-nl");
        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addCreator("Creator");
        document.addTitle("title");
        writer.setTagged();
        writer.createXmpMetadata();
        document.open();
        File file = new File("resources/data/sRGB_CS_profile.icm");
        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile
                .getInstance(new FileInputStream(file));
        writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
        Paragraph element = new Paragraph("Hello World", font);
        document.add(element);
        Image logoImage = Image.getInstance(LOGO);
        logoImage.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString("Logo"));
        document.add(logoImage);
        document.close();
    }
```

You can add the *PdfAWriter* class to your application by adding a dependency on com.itextpdf.itext-pdfa.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext-pdfa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Source: [iText 5 Pdf/A1 Example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/archiving-and-accessibility-itext5/pdfa-1)

Answer (score 0):

First kudos to @KevinWillems for the PDF/A suggestion.
I will have a look at it soon.

But meanwhile, I fixed my own problem. In this post I have all code in one method but in reality, I have several methods that get called. One of them is to set the margins and metadata. In this method I also called `document.open();`. Versions prior to v5.5.8 didn't break on this but newer ones do. Probably because the document is opened twice and only one is closed/freed.
After removing the second `document.open();` Acrobat Reader did no long complained and the verification past as well.